# Write text on the screen with LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I want to write text on the screen for my game, for things like fps, random text for items and stuff. How can I write that text?

Is it possible without the Basic Game class? Isn't there a command like this `g.drawString("Hello World", 100, 100);`?

Comment: LWJGL is really quite a thin wrapper around OpenGL - if you want to do things like this more simply I'd suggest something like JMonkey which provides a scenegraph API.

Comment: are you saying that its better move to a game engine if i want to write text?

Comment: You say you're looking for a simple `drawString()` type method, which implies you want simplicity - JMonkey will make things simpler in this respect (and many others).

Answer (score 5):

Update: this answer is now outdated, and does not work at all with the latest versions of LWJGL. Until I update this answer fully, I recommend that you look here: https://jvm-gaming.org/t/lwjgl-stb-bindings/54537

---

You could use the TrueType fonts feature in the [Slick-util](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Introduction) library.

Using a common font is easy, just create the font like this:

```
TrueTypeFont font;
Font awtFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24); //name, style (PLAIN, BOLD, or ITALIC), size
font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false); //base Font, anti-aliasing true/false
```

If you want to load the font from a `.ttf` file, it's a little more tricky:

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("myfont.ttf");
    
    Font awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream);
    awtFont = awtFont.deriveFont(24f); // set font size
    font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);
        
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After you have successfully created a `TrueTypeFont`, you can draw it like this:

```
font.drawString(100, 50, "ABC123", Color.yellow); //x, y, string to draw, color
```

For more information, you can look at the documentation for [`TrueTypeFont`](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/TrueTypeFont.html) and [`java.awt.Font`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html), and the [Slick-Util tutorial](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_3_-_TrueType_Fonts_for_LWJGL) I got most of this code from.

Comment: Could you please update the links? They have already expired. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf Thanks for letting me know; I'll get to it when I can.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and none of them worked for me. The first one was printing just a yellow Rect at the specified location in the window. I tried the second option, by loading Consolas.ttf from my Control Panel into a directory  in my project folder and used the inputStream just like in your example but it did not work. It still drew just a yellow Reck. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try Making a `BufferedImage` of required size. Then get its Graphics and draw a String. Then Convert it to a `ByteBuffer` and render it in `OpenGL`.

```
String text = "ABCD";
int s = 256; //Take whatever size suits you.
BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(s, s, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
Graphics2D g = b.createGraphics();
g.drawString(text, 0, 0);

int co = b.getColorModel().getNumComponents();

byte[] data = new byte[co * s * s];
b.getRaster().getDataElements(0, 0, s, s, data);

ByteBuffer pixels = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(data.length);
pixels.put(data);
pixels.rewind();
```

Now `pixels` contains the required Image data you need to draw.
Use `GL11.glTexImage2D()` function to draw the byte buffer.

Comment: could you please explain how we can use the `glTexImage2D()` in this case?

Comment: could you please explain how we can use the `glTexImage2D()` in this case?